# How to discover request body from Laravel to generate OpenAPI spec?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, openapi

The OpenAPI spec supports request bodys (mostly useful for POST requests.  etc.):

```
    paths:
      /pets:
        post:
          summary: Add a new pet
          requestBody:
            description: Optional description in *Markdown*
            required: true
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
          responses:
            '201':
              description: Created
```

Laravel request methods usually look something like this:

```php
public function create(JsonRequest $request): UserResource
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    $user = User::create($data);
    $user->save();
    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

Is there a way to discover the request body (which fields it may include / requires, which types the fields have) from this to be able to include this in the API spec?